# JBoss url rewrite

Tags: rewrite, jboss

I'm trying to rewrite the URL by defining various patterns in the standalone.xml of my JBoss configuration.

This is how it looks like right now:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="example.com"/>
    <rewrite pattern="^/$" substitution="foo$1" flags="nocase"/>
    <rewrite pattern="^bar$" substitution="foo$1" flags="nocase"/>
 </virtual-server>
```

But neither of these work! I have a jruby application set up with torquebox on /foo, if that matters. I wouldn't mind setting the rewrites in another file, if that works better. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the rewrite will be processed unless it matches a webapp.

Try deploying your application into ROOT instead of foo.

Comment: not my first preference, but I ended up doing that. thanks...